# Can't open cocoa emacs from terminal using open -a

Tags: macos, mac, emacs

I installed emacs on my MacBook Air running Mac OS X 10.6.5 from this site http://emacsformacosx.com/. I believe this is what used to be called cocoa emacs. I dragged it into my Application folder and it works fine when I run it from there. I want to be able to run it from the Terminal. After some googling, I tried `open -a /Application/Emacs.app foo.txt` (foo.txt was and existing file). I got two emacs windows - one with welcome screen and one with foo.txt loaded. I tried a few applications in the /Applications directory and they did not seem to behave like this. I had installed it using my own account (an admin account) so after doing `ls -l` on `/Application` I noticed that the owner and group were different from the other entries in this folder. I recursively changed the owner and group to root and wheel, like the others, but this did not help. The only thing that looks funny now is that there that ls -l show a @ character which has something to do with extended attributes but I don't know how to check these.

Any suggestions on what to check next?

Is using the open command the only to run the program? Can I simulate what it does using a shell script?

Comment: do you want emacs to load /in/ the Terminal window? Or do you want it to spawn window like you described? I figure, if you're in Terminal, you might just want to run emacs in Terminal, but I could be wrong. Asmus' suggestion would work if you want the former.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how `open` works: With your command `open /Application/Emacs.app foo.txt` you tell `open` to open two files, namely Emacs and the txt file, but these are two different operations: First, emacs will be started, and then `foo.txt` will be loaded with the default program for `.txt` files, which is apparently Emacs in your case.

As long as Emacs is the default for this file type, just using `open foo.txt` would open the file in Emacs, but if it is not the default, you would have to use `open foo.txt -a /Applications/Emacs.app` (the `-a` switch tells open what application to use) or maybe you could hand it over as a parameter with the `--args` option like this: `open /Applications/Emacs.app --args foo.txt`.

Comment: He *is* using the `-a` switch.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is a bit strange; for my installation (which I did with homebrew), open -a Emacs file.txt works fine… maybe you should rebuild your LaunchServices database? But anyway, you should be able to call the executable directly with

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs file.txt
```